# Symmetric Simple Random Walk - Definition Clarification

Tags: stochastic-processes, notation, markov-chains, markov-process, random-walk

I'm finding conflicting answers everywhere, including in my own notes.

In the phrase "symmetric simple random walk", which part, "symmetric" or "simple" refers to having a probability of $0.5$ to go up/down, and which part refers to going up/down the same amount (i.e. $1$ unit)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple means the possible transitions are only immediate left/right. Symmetric means the two transition probabilities are equal.

Comment: What do you mean by "immediate left/right"?

Comment: @IrregularUser From $X_n$ you can go to $X_n-1$ or $X_n+1$, but nowhere else.